# Why is ProvidePlugin not working well with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, webpack-2

I'm moving a project from `gulp` and `bower` to `npm` and `webpack`. The old system is building two files called `framework.js` and `vendor.js`.

In the new configuration, I created two entry points:

```
entry: {
  framework: './src/index.js',
  vendor: './src/vendor.js'
}
```

- *framework* points to the applications
- *vendor* points to a file which only includes some third party library like `angular@1.5.8`, `modernizr`, `jquery`, ... Once bundled, it's supposed to be deploy to a CDN

**NOTE** `framework` does NOT use `vendor`.

Webpack is compiling without problem, and `framework` is working well. But every time I use `vendor`

```
<script src="//cdn..../vendor.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I get plenty of `angular is not defined`, `angular.module is not a function`, `jQuery is not defined`, `$ is not defined`.

I tried to fix it using the `ProvidePlugin` like this:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  angular: 'angular',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  $: 'jquery',
  'window.$': 'jquery'
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
})
```

but it does not work for `angular` and `$`, but it works for 'jQuery`.

I also tried using `CommonsChunkPlugins`, `exports-loader`, `alias` and `externals`, but I always get the same error.

Does someone knows more about this error ? Do you have any idea of how to solve it ?